# Create a ListView that is fed by two ArrayLists at once OR two ListViews that appear as one in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

Basically, what i wanna do:

- A listView fed by two ArrayLists at once, and each list put in a section
- Two ListViews that appear to the user like one, so if you scroll to the end of the first ListView you can smoothly scroll down further down the secound listView.

Yet i lag of knowledge to do so.

Following are some details on the problem i need to solve and why i am seeking a soloution like stated above.

I am trying to build a rather complex listview in android. Its data is stored in one ArrayList at the moment. Each row's data is provided by a custom object. I sorted the entries by date,
which works fine. I now need to

- **Split that table into two sections** based on wheather a secound date provided by my custom object lies in the past or not (so basically **based on a boolean**)
- **Add a seperator** in custom design **between those two sections**
- If any of my two sections is empty, i need to ad the **coresponding placeholder** showing a message

This begs for a soloution involving two lists, it would be way easier to sort the entries and to handle design.

In case you ask what i tried: I already worked around it by mapping the relevant days way more into the future so they are on top of the list

```
Collections.sort(newsList, new Comparator<News>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(News p1, News p2) {
                DateTime startDate = new DateTime(p2.getValidUntil());
                DateTime endDate = new DateTime(p1.getValidUntil());
                if(Util.isEntryRelevant(p1)){
                    endDate = endDate.plusDays(1000);
                }
                if(Util.isEntryRelevant(p2)){
                    startDate.plusDays(1000);
                }

                Minutes diff = Minutes.minutesBetween(endDate, startDate);
                diff.getMinutes();
                return diff.getMinutes();
            }

        });
```

Which is probably the dodgiest piece of code ive written so far. A few more workarounds come to my mind, but they all seem to get messy and unclean.

Comment: why don't you create a custom adapter (by extending ArrayAdapter) that overrides getView and getCount?  that would allow you to return first list and second list from getView and also include the separator if needed or empty content.

Comment: I do hava a custom adapter wich overrides getView and getCount. But how do i get it to return me the correct list item for each view? that would result in something like if(location>newsItems1.size())return newsItems2.get(location+newsItems); and so on in getItem

Comment: but it doesnt seem like a clean solution to me, or is this the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you have to implement a custom BaseAdapter that knows to iterate over your two data sources. You could save yourself some time by using something like [this](http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/07/section-adapter.html) to which you can add several regular adapters.